# Get learning rate of keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I cannot seem to get the value of learning rate. What I get is below.

I've tried the model for 200 epochs and want to see/change the learning rate. Is this not the correct way?

```
>>> print(ig_cnn_model.optimizer.lr)
<tf.Variable 'lr_6:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7874).

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Already saw that before I posted here. For them it returns a values, AFIK.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `eval()` from `keras.backend`:

```py
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

print(K.eval(model.optimizer.lr))
```

Output:

```
0.001
```

Comment: What if I want to reset the learning rate?  e.g. something like `model.optimizer.lr=10`?

Comment: Or `model.optimizer.lr.numpy()` in recent tensorflow versions. `lr` is just a variable, so assigning it works as usual: `model.optimizer.lr.assign(0.1)`

Answer (score 26):

The best way to get all information related to the optimizer would be with `.get_config()`.

Example:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizerF,
                  loss=lossF,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.optimizer.get_config()

>>> {'name': 'Adam', 'learning_rate': 0.001, 'decay': 0.0, 'beta_1': 0.9, 'beta_2': 0.999, 'epsilon': 1e-07, 'amsgrad': False}
```

It returns a dict with all information.

Answer (score 19):

You can change your learning rate by

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Op was asking how to GET the learning rate. Not set. Note that Keras allow dynamical changing of lr, so it's possible that you want to know the lr at a later stage after a few epochs of training

Answer (score 3):

With Tensorflow >=2.0:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

In [3]: opt.lr.numpy()
Out[3]: 0.001
```

`lr` is just a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), so its value can be changed via [`assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign) method:

```
In [4]: opt.lr.assign(0.1)
Out[4]: <tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=0.1>

In [5]: opt.lr.numpy()
Out[5]: 0.1
```

Same goes with the rest of hyperparameters:

```
In [6]: opt.decay.numpy()
Out[6]: 0.0

In [7]: opt.beta_1.numpy()
Out[7]: 0.9

In [8]: opt.beta_2.numpy()
Out[8]: 0.999
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a [learning rate schedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules) in tf2 and want to access the learning rate while the model is training, you can define a custom callback. This is an example for a callback which prints the learning rate at every epoch:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

class PrintLearningRate(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        lr = K.eval(self.model.optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float64)
        print("\nLearning rate at epoch {} is {}".format(epoch, lr)))
```

Notice how for learning rate schedulers, in tf2 the learning rate can be accessed via `_decayed_lr()`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way:

1. create an optimizer instance

> opt = keras.optimizers.SGD()

2. get the learning rate from the instance

> print('learning rate={}'.format(opt.lr.numpy()))

3. use the optimizer in the model

> model.compile(optimizer = opt, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the optimizers don't include their names in the configs.

Here is a complete example on how to get the configs **and** how to reconstruct (i.e. clone) the optimizer from their configs (which includes the learning rate as well).

```
import keras.optimizers as opt

def get_opt_config(optimizer):
    """
    Extract Optimizer Configs from an instance of
    keras Optimizer
    :param optimizer: instance of keras Optimizer.
    :return: dict of optimizer configs.
    """
    if not isinstance(optimizer, opt.Optimizer):
        raise TypeError('optimizer should be instance of '
                        'keras.optimizers.Optimizer '
                        'Got {}.'.format(type(optimizer)))
    opt_config = optimizer.get_config()
    if 'name' not in opt_config.keys():
        _name = str(optimizer.__class__).split('.')[-1] \
            .replace('\'', '').replace('>', '')
        opt_config.update({'name': _name})
    return opt_config


def clone_opt(opt_config):
    """
    Clone keras optimizer from its configurations.
    :param opt_config: dict, keras optimizer configs.
    :return: instance of keras optimizer.
    """
    if not isinstance(opt_config, dict):
        raise TypeError('opt_config must be a dict. '
                        'Got {}'.format(type(opt_config)))
    if 'name' not in opt_config.keys():
        raise ValueError('could not find the name of optimizer in opt_config')
    name = opt_config.get('name')
    params = {k: opt_config[k] for k in opt_config.keys() if k != 'name'}
    if name.upper() == 'ADAM':
        return opt.Adam(**params)
    if name.upper() == 'NADAM':
        return opt.Nadam(**params)
    if name.upper() == 'ADAMAX':
        return opt.Adamax(**params)
    if name.upper() == 'ADADELTA':
        return opt.Adadelta(**params)
    if name.upper() == 'ADAGRAD':
        return opt.Adagrad(**params)
    if name.upper() == 'RMSPROP':
        return opt.RMSprop()
    if name.upper() == 'SGD':
        return opt.SGD(**params)
    raise ValueError('Unknown optimizer name. Available are: '
                     '(\'adam\',\'sgd\', \'rmsprop\', \'adagrad\', '
                     '\'adadelta\', \'adamax\', \'nadam\'). '
                     'Got {}.'.format(name))
```

### Test

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rmsprop = opt.RMSprop()
    configs = get_opt_config(rmsprop)
    print(configs)
    cloned_rmsprop = clone_opt(configs)
    print(cloned_rmsprop)
    print(cloned_rmsprop.get_config())
```

### Outputs

```
{'lr': 0.0010000000474974513, 'rho': 0.8999999761581421, 'decay': 0.0, 'epsilon': 1e-07, 'name': 'RMSprop'}
<keras.optimizers.RMSprop object at 0x7f96370a9358>
{'lr': 0.0010000000474974513, 'rho': 0.8999999761581421, 'decay': 0.0, 'epsilon': 1e-07}
```

Comment: `str(optimizer.__class__).split(..)...` -> `optimizer.__class__.__name__`